# Unable to start Emulator Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 the problem is that Emulator is not Launching App and I am getting the error `Installation did not succeed` I tried to Clean and Rebuild the project but Still I am facing the same problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

[Screenshot of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhLkR.jpg)

Comment: try deleting the emulator and create again.

Comment: Have you tried killing the adb kill-server and then try again? Also you can clear the cache and restart Android Studio and do the same on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following the steps below.

**Step 1**

Go to File and then select Invalidate caches/ Restart.

**File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**

**Step 2**

Delete the existing emulator.

**Step 3**

Create a new Emulator and then run the app.